# Image slide show excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to load images from any specific folder. I want to add start and stop button to this slide show. I also want to add Drop down to go for specific image, which is in destination folder.

```
Sub Imageshow()
On Error Resume Next
Dim objFSO, oFO, oFolder, oFile, picDir, IE, Locus
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
picDir = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"
Set oFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(picDir)
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .MenuBar = 0
    .Toolbar = 0
    .StatusBar = 0
    .navigate "About:Blank"
End With
 'wait a while until IE as finished to load
Do While IE.busy
Loop

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If Right(oFile.Name, 3) = "jpg" Or Right(oFile.Name, 3) = "gif" Then
        Locus = "file://" & Replace(oFile.ParentFolder, "\", "/") & "/" & oFile.Name
        With IE.document
            .Open
            .WriteLn "<HTML><HEAD>"
            .WriteLn "<TITLE>Slide Show</TITLE></HEAD>"
            .WriteLn "<BODY>"
            .WriteLn "Hello world<br><Br>"
            .WriteLn "<img src='" & Locus & "'><br>"
            .WriteLn "</BODY>"
            .WriteLn "</HTML>"
            .Close
        End With
        IE.Visible = True
        WScript.Sleep 2000
    End If
Next

Set IE = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
WScript.Quit (0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere, that I didn't recognize? What does not work, what's your error message?

Comment: No error occured by i need some changes for some other purpose..

Comment: Please change your question accordingly

Comment: I only want to create a slide show in excel